# Where can we get the list of questions from the 2019 Developer Survey?

Tags: feature-request, survey-2019

Now that the 2019 survey results are published, I'd like to be able to tie the results back to the actual questions asked in the survey.  The trouble is, I can't find a way to get the list of actual questions asked on the survey.

When you try to go to the survey site, the resulting page says that the survey is closed.  Searching Meta SO and Google didn't seem to yield anything.  Is there a place we can go to get the actual questions on the 2019 survey, and perhaps even some way to map back the results to the questions (especially if the link between the two is non-obvious).  Ideally the survey result report itself would restate or link to the original questions so that this info is easy to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We will be releasing the anonymized results for the survey within the next 6 weeks. You can find [previous years' results here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/), where the 2019 results will also be available soon. For each year, there is a zip archive that includes both respondents' answers (CSV) as well as a CSV and PDF showing how each question was exactly stated on the survey. You can check out last year's zip archive to see what to expect for this year.

Comment: Next 6 weeks or next *6 to 8 weeks*? :P